# Linux aio (not posix) examples?

Tags: c, linux, io, linux-kernel

Does anyone have experience with Linux aio functions (io_*, not posix aio)? It would be great if someone could provide a link to some examples (or provide some examples here). Also, what are your general observations/comments about their use?

I am working on an I/O library and someone suggested I have a look at them. They are known to perform better than POSIX aio in certain cases and I would like to have a look.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer, but except in the most extreme situations, choosing a complex nonstandard API merely for the sake of performance is probably a really big mistake, especially when the difference will be marginal at best. A better approach if you don't like POSIX AIO (which is a very very ugly and painful API) would be to just create dedicated IO threads.

Comment: True. I do have dedicated threads in my library for I/O. But I had a short chat with a guy who said he saw significantly better performance when he wrote files in random order using linux io_* functions, as compared with 'write' and 'aio_write'. Hence the curiosity.

Comment: Did he try `pwrite`? If you're using `write` for "random order", you're going to incur a huge additional cost in syscall overhead merely by making the extra `lseek` call before each `write`. You might also try `posix_fadvise` to hint to the kernel that you intend to perform random access.

Comment: He did not mention _pwrite_, so my guess is that he did not, which is why I was curious to try it out. I have been researching since a couple of hours, and _io_prep_pwrite_ seems to be one of the aio functions.

Comment: Found an example [here](http://lse.sourceforge.net/io/aio.html), under the section "Daniel McNiel's (OSDL) aiocp test"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: [this shows](http://www.xmailserver.org/eventfd-aio-test.c) an example for the native linux io interface

([This is an example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-async/) on the posix aio interface).

As to some of the commentters on the question: the aio library allows a program to issue multiple parallel request in a way where the kernel can execute them in the order which is most efficient for seeks and disk rotation -- i.e. the io request may not be executed in the order which they were issues which is different from making synchronous request in a thread.  In very IO intensive applications this *can* dramatically increase IO performance, but for most applications it will just add complexity.

Comment: I don't buy it.  _All_ writes go to the page cache before they go to disk.  (Well, unless you use `O_DIRECT`, but that is not what we are talking about.)  So the kernel has plenty of time -- seconds, typically -- to accumulate writes and arrange the actual disk accesses for optimal performance.

Comment: Well, If I allow READs to be executed in any order I get the performance benefit as described -- I.e. if I don't care of the order I read stuff in, but just know I need to read these 1000 different things, I can let the OS and the disk determine the order I should get it.

Comment: And with O_DIRECT on write I also get the same benefit, and if I was to implement a database which needed to make a commit of several updates in many tables, I would need this functionality to get best performance.

Comment: Thanks @soren, When you say the kernel can execute writes in an efficient order, did you find that through some experiments or through documentation? If its documented, could you post a link?